# django model forms fields template dry

Tags: django

We have a django application with tons of forms with generic template for rendering all form fields. Here is an example of one such form template.

```
{% for field in form %}
{% include "templates/_pratial/_field.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

_field.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ field }}
  </div>
```

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-control'})
```

Now we are updating our layout with new html , our form now should look like this

```
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="control-label" for="email">
   {{ field.label }}
  </label>
  <div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="{{ field.?? }}"></i>  //fa fa-envelope-o
   </div>
   {{ field }}
  </div>
 </div>
```

How can i dynamically insert **fa fa-envelope-o**, without breaking **dry**

Some thing like

```
self.fields['myfield'].icon = "fa fa-envelope-o"
```

in form init and can be easily used in template like {{ field.icon }}

Comment: It seems you need to play around with a custom widget.

Comment: Maybe you could try out custom form field for this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#creating-custom-fields

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyNewCharField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self, my_class=None, **kwargs):
        super(MyNewCharField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_class_name = my_class_name
```

You can inherit the form fields you want to create a new field, and add an additional attribute like 'my_class' as shown in the above example and initialize the class_name in the forms **init** itself.

Comment: thnx but there are over 1k total fields used in project i cannot override them all

Comment: Anyways you would have to specify the classname for all these 1k fields right? What I am saying is that, you can use your custom fields instead of using the django from fields wherever needed and specify the class_name in the form init itself.